# init a new Postgres 15 db as Airflow's backend

Tags: postgresql, docker, permissions, airflow, amazon-rds

That's should be a fairly easy task -
I'm trying to bringup a new Airflow cluster (should be [supported](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#choosing-database-backend)).

I chose **Postgres 15.2** engine in AWS RDS (currently the latest version) and followed the [instructions](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#setting-up-a-postgresql-database).

While running the `airflow db init` command I got the following exception:

```
[2023-03-05 21:43:13,139] {db.py:1448} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1705, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 716, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: permission denied for schema public
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
                     ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/venv/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 38, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 51, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 35, in initdb
    db.initdb()
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 71, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 648, in initdb
    upgradedb(session=session)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 1449, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, revision=to_revision or 'heads')
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 378, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 569, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 94, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 110, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 107, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 101, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 867, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 606, in run_migrations
    self._ensure_version_table()
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 544, in _ensure_version_table
    self._version.create(self.connection, checkfirst=True)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 943, in create
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2016, in _run_ddl_visitor
    visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 483, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 890, in visit_table
    self.connection.execute(
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 77, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1290, in _execute_ddl
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1748, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1929, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1705, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 716, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for schema public
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
                     ^

[SQL:
CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
    version_num VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT alembic_version_pkc PRIMARY KEY (version_num)
)

]
```

After digging around I've found that Postgres 15 [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/15.0/) states that:

> Remove PUBLIC creation permission on the public schema

I also reproduced it locally with docker, if I set only `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` (**without** `POSTGRES_USER` & `POSTGRES_DB`!):

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.2
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456

    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - airflow-postgres-vol-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  airflow-postgres-vol-data:
```

It fails as well.
One workaround that worked was:

```
ALTER USER airflow_user WITH SUPERUSER;
```

but it seems like a wrong solution (too much power for `airflow_user`) - as it worked as a non superuser in a previous Postges versions.

What is the right/recommended way of initializing Postgres-15 as Airflow's backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after creating the database and the user as explained in Airflow's [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#setting-up-a-postgresql-database):

```
CREATE DATABASE airflow_db;
CREATE USER airflow_user WITH PASSWORD 'airflow_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE airflow_db TO airflow_user;
```

I had to **switch** to the new database and then add privileges:

```
USE airflow_db;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO airflow_user;
```